# How to get FirendlyName of OIDs associated with X509Certificate2?

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, x509certificate, x509certificate2

Is there a way to get *friendly name* for valid OID?

For example, I have OID `1.2.840.113549.1.1`, which represents `SHA1 with RSA signature`. How to get friendly name that would `X509Certificate2.SignatureAlgorithm.FriendlyName` return?

I have tried to create `var oid = new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.1")`, and looking into `oid.FriendlyName` property, it is `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all OIDs have mapped FriendlyName values.

[1.2.840.113549.1.1](http://oid-info.com/get/1.2.840.113549.1.1) is the PKCS#1 arc, but it's never used directly, just as a namespace; so Windows apparently doesn't feel that it's useful to provide a FriendlyName value for it.

sha1WithRsaEncryption is 1.2.840.113549.1.1.5 (or "[{ pkcs-1 5 }](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447#appendix-A.2.4)", if you prefer), and `new Oid("1.2.840.113549.1.1.5").FriendlyName` will return `"sha1RSA"` on .NET Framework and .NET Core.

For "most" OIDs the friendly name resolution is done by calling into the system cryptography libraries, but .NET Core [hard codes that one](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding/src/Internal/Cryptography/OidLookup.cs#L192), ensuring it maps the same on all OSes.